# Develop iPhone App on Windows / Compile on Remote Mac

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I realize it's been asked countless times whether iPhone apps can be built in Windows and that the simple answer is no, with workarounds such as using VM or even something like Dragon SDK which requires the app to be written in C/C++, but I would like to build an app using Objective C.

My question is can the code for an iPhone app not be developed on a Windows computer, uploaded to a remote Mac computer, compiled on the Mac, and then downloaded back to Windows to install via iTunes? I don't want to buy a Mac mini to get my feet wet with iPhone development, but I don't want to be limited to writing an HTML 5 app using Phone Gap or similar.

If nothing else, wouldn't it be possible to develop the app directly on a remote / virtual Mac using a remote desktop connection?

If either of these are possible, does anyone know of a company offering such a service? If not, what would be a likely reason that it hasn't been created? It seems like there would be enormous demand.

Comment: I'd think this is *possible* on a certain level. You could use Xcode's command line utilities to build an ad-hoc distribution binary from the terminal after editing the files remotely (although good luck with Interface Builder). But if you are doing this to get a taste of a new platform, don't you think this sounds like a nightmare? Waiting for every build to come through ftp to install through iTunes? Denied the native SDK and its doc browser? You would hate iOS development automatically if you worked like this, I think. Your decision of course but sounds like a terrible experience to me.

Comment: I'm used to writing code on a remote server either through putty or a mapped drive--a little slow at times but not too bad. I'm not sure how much visual manipulation is required, but it doesn't seem too bad to transfer code back and forth. I think ideally would be a remote desktop connection to use an sdk installed on the remote mac. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That part wouldn't be bad, and I do think the remote desktop idea is worth a shot. But trying to install (slow) and debug (almost impossible) by installing through iTunes, and eschewing interface builder, eschewing Xcode, that sends shivers up my spine, and avoiding that would be well worth the price of a retina MacBook Pro, certainly a Mac Mini!

Comment: But for a real answer I don't know of any services that will let you rent a Mac for screen sharing, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the Mac in Cloud service mentioned below looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: _“can the code for an iPhone app **not** be developed on a Windows computer”_  Yes.  That's the normal way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps http://www.macincloud.com/ is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you're trying to do is not possible but how about MonoTouch ?
http://xamarin.com/monotouch

Using .NET on Windows technologies to develop iPhone and other apps ?

Comment: Thanks, if it comes to this, I'll compare MonoTouch to the other similar alternatives. I do prefer C# over C++ like Dragon SDK requires. Ultimately, my goal is to use a remote Mac to write Objective C applications that would be indistinguishable from apps written directly on a Mac.